# Execute code every 10 seconds but start on 0 seconds too

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I want to execute code every 10 seconds, but also on page load. I mean I want the code to execute when the page loads initially then every 10 seconds. The following code only executes the code initially after 10 seconds.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  /// call your function here
}, 10000);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could make that a real function that you call, then on pageLoad just call your function. Simple change.

Comment: Since the OP accepted the answer without jQuery, I've now removed the jQuery tag from the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this :

```
(function(){
   var f = function() {
     // do something
   };
   window.setInterval(f, 10000);
   f();
})();
```

The [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) is used here to avoid polluting the enclosing namespace.

Answer (score 3):

First execute the function in `$.ready` and then start the interval with that same function.

Something along the lines of:

```
$(function() {
    var f = function() { };

    f();
    window.setInterval(f, 10000);
});
```

Comment: Sure, but the OP wanted to execute the function "also on page load".

Comment: Right, missed that part. :)

Comment: Apparently the OP did not want the function to execute in `jQuery.ready` after all since he accepted the other answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't inline the function, and then just call it immediately:

```
window.setInterval(foo, 10000);
foo();

function foo()
{
    //Do Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I create [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/k7dC3/) try this

```
functionCall();
function functionCall(){

window.setInterval(function(){
  /// call your function here
}, 10000);
}
```

Comment: @user1937021 you can use this.Try it once